# OpenVPN verify-x509-name

Tags: raspbian

I'm setting up a vpn tunnel on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Wheezy 7), and when attempting to run the following command, I get an error.

Command: `sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/ipvanish-NL-Amsterdam-ams-a28.ovpn --auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/login.txt`

Error: `Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in ipvanish-NL-Amsterdam-ams-a28.ovpn:11: verify-x509-name (2.2.1)
Use --help for more information.`

When I omit the last parameter (--auth...), I still get the same error.

The contents of `/etc/openvpn` are the following files:
`ca.ipvanish.com.crt`, `login.txt`, `ipvanish_NL-Amsterdam-ams-a28.ovpn` and `update-resolv.conf`.

`login.txt` contains my ipvanish credentials and `ipvanish_NL-Amsterdam-ams-a28.ovpn` (supplied by ipvanish), has the following contents:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ams-a28.ipvanish.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
persist-remote-ip
ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
verify-x509-name ams-a28.ipvanish.com name
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TL$
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your getting that error because the server certificate Common Name [CN] and Subject Alternative Name [SAN] literal string does not match the literal string in "verify-x509-name ams-a28.ipvanish.com name"

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of `OpenVPN (2.2.1)`, where `verify-x509-name` has not been yet implemented. This option replaced `tls-remote` that served the similar purpose in release `2.2.3`.

You can either upgrade your OpenVPN to at least `2.2.3`, or you can replace `verify-x509-name` line in your config with `tls-remote ams-a28.ipvanish.com`, this should make it work.